# How to change TFTP root Directory

Tags: rhel, directory, tftp

How can I change root Directory of TFTP in RHEL 6 ?

Default Location is `/var/lib/tftpboot`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIR You should could it in /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

```
 service tftp
 {
     ...
     server_args             = -s /your/location/to/tftpboot
```